# Portable class library and Universal Windows App with Kinect v2

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, kinect, portable-class-library, windows-10-universal

Using Visual Studio 2015, I need to create a Universal Windows App and I want to add a Portable Class Library in the same solution. In this Portable Class Library I want to add a reference to Microsoft.Kinect.dll . But when I execute the code in Local Machine, I get the following error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.BadImageFormatException' in AppKinect.exe
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Kinect, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)

Is it possible to solve this problem? Could I add a reference to this .dll in order to indirectly use Kinect v2 in Universal Windows app? As I read that for now Universal Windows app doesn't support using Kinect v2.

I also try to add a manual reference to Microsoft.Kinect.dll using

```
AssemblyName longName = new AssemblyName("Microsoft.Kinect.dll, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");
Assembly assem = Assembly.Load(longName);
```

but I obtain the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But the *Microsoft.Kinect.dll* is not applicable to PCL projects, right? You most likely need to develop a UWP-specific class library and reference the [Kinect for Windows SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/kinect/tools) from there.

Comment: You're right. Anyway, how can I make this reference? I'm sorry but until now I've only developed a WPF application in order to use Microsoft Kinect for my purposes.

Comment: I am no Kinect developer myself, so I don't know the details. But I am pretty sure you will find some answers if you follow the link to the SDK I gave above.